# Use local C# values in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8.1

I was wondering if there is a way to use local values (any kind, string, int, etc.) in `JavaScript` function. To clarify what I mean:

I would be using an `InvokeScriptAsync` method of WebView as follows

```
string invokeScripts = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
{
    @"(function()
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByName(HERE I WANT MY LOCAL VALUE)[0].tagName;
        x.setAttribute('value', 'myValue');
    })()"
});
```

So it would take some value that was initialized before and place it on placeholder.

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 project here and the language is C#.

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: You can use Ajax calls to your server to get any value you want:

For example, you need to get the value of a Const String `"abc"`  which is initialized at the server side.

1) Prepare your ajax call URL:
Prepare a suitable path for a ajax call like `/my_app/api/getConstABC` 

2) Get value at js side
Prepare an ajax call at js side to get the value like:
For example in AngularJS1:

`$http.get("/my_app/api/getConstABC").success(function(response) {var something = response.data;});`

Answer (score 2):

Since is a simple string you can format it using your variabile before to send it to the client, like:

```
string invokeScripts = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
{
    String.Format(@"(function()
    {{
        var x = document.getElementsByName('{0}')[0].tagName;
        x.setAttribute('value', 'myValue');
    }})()",HERE I WANT MY LOCAL VALUE)
});
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/F6jam9

Comment: Wow, this easy? I will give it ago in a second and let you know how it went.

Comment: Ok, so I've received a 'System.FormatException' with additional information on: Input string was not in a correct format. 
Any hints?

Comment: @MrMe because of string.format you need to double { and }, edited

Comment: With double curly brackets I'm receiving HRESULT: 0x80020101 (incorrect syntax) error. And adding braces around the value doesn't change anything. 
Maybe I was bad with explaining. What I want to do in the end is find the value on website by it's name (which I want to specify locally) and then do something with it. But first, I need to find it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MrMe it's a client issue, is the script working or x is a null object? You have to check it in the console

Comment: Well when I try to produce a function string (like you displayed in your demo) I get a correct string. However, when I try to use it with InvokeScriptAsync it gives me this bad syntax error. Don't have any other ideas anymore.

Comment: I have even added the escape sequences thinking that I would need to generate a complete function string. [This is how it looks at the momment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U4YyLd)

Comment: No. I keep on receiving bad syntax errors no matter what. I have another function where I do not need to use local values (thus I don't use String.Format) and that one works on the same WebView. However, this one doesn't. That makes me think that String.Format method changes the string to something that doesn't match to the syntax. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MrMe I'm sorry for the delay; why the double @ in the string? The string.format create a noral string, can you try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SM7P7